# Expect Script Terminating on its own

Tags: expect

I have written the below expect script but it's not working as expected. I want the script to terminate automatically when all the commands are executed. However , the script either never terminates ( if set timeout -1 is used ) or terminates within seconds even before my commands are executed. Can someone please help ?

Here's the script :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

spawn su vserve
set password vserve
set PWD whoami

set cmdstr(0) "bash /apps/vpn/vserve/vserve_profile"
set cmdstr(1) "bash /apps/vpn/asap/scripts/change_loopback.sh"
set timeout -1
expect "*Password:*" {
sleep 1
send "$password\r"
send "$PWD\r"
sleep 1

for {set i 0} {$i<[array size cmdstr]} {incr i} {
send "$cmdstr($i)\r"

}

send \"exit\r\"
expect eof
}
```

Comment: Can someone please answer my query ? I am really struggling with it. Thanks..

Comment: put `exp_internal 1` as the first line of your script. See what expect tells you. When your script hangs with `set timeout -1` that means one of your expect patterns is not matching.

Comment: Also `send \"exit\r\"` is wrong. you're sending the command `"exit` (with the quote

Answer (score 1):

Usually in an interactive shell, you have to `expect` the specific shell prompt before you `send` next command. That's the way we make sure the previous command has really finished.

Comment: Thanks , It worked :) Here's what I did :

    send "$EXIT\r"
    expect "$"
    expect eof